# Why does Amazon EC2 CPU Utilization alarm spike impossibly high?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cpu, alarm

I may be just doing this wrong, but when I create CPU Utilization alarms for my EC2 boxes at AWS, I'm suddenly seeing these really strange spikes every now and then.

I have an alarm set to email me when CPU Utilization gets above 80%. The normal CPU load is pretty low on these particular boxes so I should almost never get notified, however I'm seeing these spikes that seem totally wrong... like 6 Billion percent.

I don't know if I'm simply misunderstanding what is happening or if there's truly something awry here.

Here's what I'm seeing:

[image: Alarm Graph at AWS]
(ignore the 2 datapoints within 10 minutes... that was me after I changed it. It had triggered when set to 1 datapoint within 5 minutes)

Notice that when I mouse over the red line, it's like 2.5 or so:

[image: normal CPU utilization]

But the spike, when I mouse over, is something like 6 Billion!!!??:
[image: spiked CPU utilization]

Here's what the settings look like for the alert... it seems pretty normally configured to me:

[image: settings part 1]
[image: settings part 2]

So my question is simply: am I doing something wrong? Why does CPUUtilization spike up so impossibly high??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think if you are really worried you can enable detailed monitoring and get more data points it will probably be smoother then. Could just be the method which it calculated the value which is messed up for that particular extremely  sharp case. Unless something bad is actually happening in your app for this particular scenario then you can safely ignore it.

Better alarms would be something like avg CPU usage above 90% for 5 minutes or something with a data point every minute. 2 Data-points is going to give you a lot of variance from the actual average usage. The more data points you have the less likely you will randomly see 2 system events which spike the CPU for whatever reason, clearing memory etc, nothing really to worry about